# Choosing a baseball team

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ guys in school, and $q$ guys needed to make a baseball team, and there are $k$ guys interested in playing, this is $q \leq k \leq n$.

The players will be picked as follows. One guy will be the dictator, and he will have the chance to write his name on the list - but he can skip that privilege and leave if he is not interested. A dictator is chosen after him and has the same privilege, and so on until there are already $q$ people who wrote their names on the list. The dictator at each step is selected at random, with uniform probabilities for each player to be the dictator.

If I am one the persons willing to play, what is the chance that I will get to play?

HINT: The answer is $\frac{q}{k}$ but I don't know why.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the dictator cannot force anyone else to do anything? The only thing he can do is decide whether he wants to sign up himself? And then when the list is full, everyone else have to leave?

Comment: Are people lined up for selection or selected at random?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the guy uses the chance to play w.p. $p$, you need at least 1 slot in the team before you have the chance to choose. This also assumes people are lined up. Clearly the probability that all $q$ slots have been taken (assuming your position is $j$) is $P=\binom{j-1}{q}p^q(1-p)^{j-1-q}$. So the probability that you get ot play is $1- P$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each randomly chosen dictator will add his name to the list **if and only if** he is one of the $k$ people interested in playing, then the probability that you will get to play is simply $q/k$.

Here's the reasoning:  To begin with, you can ignore all the people not interested in playing; whenever one of those people is chosen as the dictator, they take a pass and the list is unchanged.  Second, the process of randomly selecting a dictator is equivalent to lining up the $k$ interested people in a (uniformly) random order and then taking the first $q$ of them.  The probability that you are among them is thus $q/k$.

Comment: Thanks Barry. I should have been more precise. I see what you say, but can you derive it using a precise formula? For example, if I am chosen within the first $q$ dictators, for sure I get the game. But if I am chosen in the $q+1$ position, then my chances are???

Comment: @JosuéOrtega, if you are in the $q+1$ position, the sign-up list won't get to you, because there will already be $q$ names on it, namely the names of the $q$ (interested) people ahead of you.  (Remember, the first step in the argument is to *ignore* anyone who isn't interested in playing.)

Comment: Yeah I see, but assume you are not deleting the ones who do not one to play. If I am in the $q+1$ position, I have a chance because there is a probability that one of the previous dictators was non willing to play!

Comment: @JosuéOrtega, I think you were responding while I was editing in the final parenthetical remark in my reply.

Comment: Yep, I see that thanks. But now don't ignore them. That is the part that puzzles me.

Comment: @JosuéOrtega, the point is, their presence has no effect on the list, so you *might at well* ignore them.  If you insist on including them, then imagine a uniformly random list of everyone created in two steps:  First create a random line-up of the $k$ people interested in playing, including yourself.  Then, one by one, insert the $n-k$ uninterested people at random in the line-up.  No matter how the second step is carried out, the probability that the sign-up list will get to you is the probability that you were among the first $q$ people in the first step's line-up.